# Flink in YARN + Checkpointing in HDFS - recurring error org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, high-availability

Flink YARN Cluster High Availability:

```
high-availability: zookeeper
high-availability.storageDir: hdfs://hann/user/flink/recovery
high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: XXX:2181
high-availability.zookeeper.path.root: /flink
state.backend: rocksdb
state.checkpoints.dir: hdfs://hann/user/flink/checkpoints
state.checkpoints.num-retained: 5
```

+ Streaming job (Каfka source -> Flink -> Some sinks)

StreamExecutionEnvironment:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.enableCheckpointing(<interval>);
env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE;
env.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(<interval>);
env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(<interval>);
env.setRestartStrategy(<restartStrategies>);
```

Work well without checkpointing but with it - periodic crashes:

```
2018-06-29 07:15:56,429 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 444 @ 1530245743320 for job cf58d818c629f8297c6331b4130db1f9.
2018-06-29 07:16:16,638 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Checkpoint 444 of job cf58d818c629f8297c6331b4130db1f9 expired before completing.
2018-06-29 07:16:16,796 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 445 @ 1530245776638 for job cf58d818c629f8297c6331b4130db1f9.
2018-06-29 07:16:24,596 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: Kafka (5/6) (5d1bb37e21bd68a04a752e62323c6d88) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
AsynchronousException{java.lang.Exception: Could not materialize checkpoint 444 for operator Source: Kafka (5/6).}
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointExceptionHandler.tryHandleCheckpointException(StreamTask.java:1154)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.handleExecutionException(StreamTask.java:948)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.run(StreamTask.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Could not materialize checkpoint 444 for operator Source: Kafka (5/6).
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.handleExecutionException(StreamTask.java:943)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Could not flush and close the file system output stream to hdfs://hann/user/flink/checkpoints/cf58d818c629f8297c6331b4130db1f9/chk-444/8ec33328-eb51-4c74-8b1b-dfc0ef185bfd in order to obtain the stream state handle
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FutureUtil.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtil.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OperatorSnapshotFinalizer.<init>(OperatorSnapshotFinalizer.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.run(StreamTask.java:854)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not flush and close the file system output stream to hdfs://hann/user/flink/checkpoints/cf58d818c629f8297c6331b4130db1f9/chk-444/8ec33328-eb51-4c74-8b1b-dfc0ef185bfd in order to obtain the stream state handle
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStreamFactory$FsCheckpointStateOutputStream.closeAndGetHandle(FsCheckpointStreamFactory.java:325)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend$1.performOperation(DefaultOperatorStateBackend.java:447)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend$1.performOperation(DefaultOperatorStateBackend.java:352)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.async.AbstractAsyncCallableWithResources.call(AbstractAsyncCallableWithResources.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FutureUtil.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtil.java:50)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on /user/flink/checkpoints/cf58d818c629f8297c6331b4130db1f9/chk-444/8ec33328-eb51-4c74-8b1b-dfc0ef185bfd (inode 97646080): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-2015925738_1 does not have any open files.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:3752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.completeFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3839)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.completeFile(FSNamesystem.java:3809)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.complete(NameNodeRpcServer.java:748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.complete(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.complete(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:551)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2222)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2220)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1401)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.complete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.complete(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:443)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.complete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.completeFile(DFSOutputStream.java:2251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.close(DFSOutputStream.java:2233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopDataOutputStream.close(HadoopDataOutputStream.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.ClosingFSDataOutputStream.close(ClosingFSDataOutputStream.java:64)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStreamFactory$FsCheckpointStateOutputStream.closeAndGetHandle(FsCheckpointStreamFactory.java:311)
    ... 12 more
```

At the same time in checkpoints dir:

```
~ # hdfs dfs -ls /user/flink/checkpoints/cf58d818c629f8297c6331b4130db1f9/
Found 6 items
drwxr-xr-x   - flink flink          0 2018-06-29 07:15 /user/flink/checkpoints/cf58d818c629f8297c6331b4130db1f9/chk-441
drwxr-xr-x   - flink flink          0 2018-06-29 07:15 /user/flink/checkpoints/cf58d818c629f8297c6331b4130db1f9/chk-442
drwxr-xr-x   - flink flink          0 2018-06-29 07:15 /user/flink/checkpoints/cf58d818c629f8297c6331b4130db1f9/chk-443
drwxr-xr-x   - flink flink          0 2018-06-29 07:16 /user/flink/checkpoints/cf58d818c629f8297c6331b4130db1f9/chk-445
drwxr-xr-x   - flink flink          0 2018-06-29 02:48 /user/flink/checkpoints/cf58d818c629f8297c6331b4130db1f9/shared
drwxr-xr-x   - flink flink          0 2018-06-29 02:48 /user/flink/checkpoints/cf58d818c629f8297c6331b4130db1f9/taskowned
```

There is **no chk-444** folder in checkpoints directory

I'm stucked =(

I tried FsStatBackend and RocksDBStateBackend and there is no difference - I get this error every 5-6 hours.

P.S.
Flink 1.5.0
Hadoop 2.6.0

Comment: Run into same issue, anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried `env.getCheckpointConfig().setFailOnCheckpointingErrors(false)` ? Won't solve the cause, but will minimize the effect.